# How to remove LiveCD after installing OS on VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox, system-installation, livecd

After going through the process of installation of a Unix OS (in this case [Mageia](http://www.mageia.org/)) on [VirtualBox 4.08](http://www.virtualbox.org/), the next step is to remove the LiveCD.

Since the LiveCD is virtual, how should one proceed to remove it? Deleting the ISO does not seem like a clean way to do this.

Should the setting be changed in the storage section?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried editing the VM configuration?

Comment: Should I go into the settings > storage and do something about the LiveCD? But what exactly I am not sure. If you know please explain. Thanks. + see edits in question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the screenshot you provided, with the Live CD selected, click the little CD icons on the right. That should provide you with a dropdown box from which you can select `Remove Disc from Virtual Drive`